# dynamically assign values to named list all with the same name

Tags: r

I want to dynamically assign values to a named list where all the names are the same.

I tried doing this, but I think it's overwriting the value with every iteration so it only stores the last value:

```
params <- c('1', '2', '3')
named_list <- list()

for (i in params){
  named_list['name'] <- i
}
```

The output is:

```
named_list
$name
[1] "3"
```

Whereas I was looking for

```
$name
[1] "1"

$name
[1] "2"

$name
[1] "3"
```

Comment: `named_list['name'] <- ` means that you always write to the same list element called "name".

Comment: would changing it to `=` create new elements?

Comment: Maybe `named_list[paste0("name", i)] <-` which would give it the name of its value pasted to name, ("name1", "name2", "name3"). The names within a list should not be the same, because you can refer to the list elements by name.

Comment: I guess it's possible but it seems very unwise. After you get such a list try selecting named_list['name'] and seeing what you do ... and don't get.

Comment: I know, I just need it to pass to a function that's making an API call and this type of list is the only way it recognizes inputs. I can't just pass a vector of parameters, every parameter needs the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
params <- c('1', '2', '3')
named_list <- list()

for (i in params){
  named_list[i] <- i
}
names(named_list) <- rep("name", length(named_list))
```

Comment: The names have to be identical

Comment: I was trying to give a generic example.. Now I updated and it will work for every size of list.